# Check if an asset exists before dinamically importing it

Tags: javascript, import, try-catch, assets, vite

Hello I'm trying to dynamically import a file and if it doesn't than I'm going to create it. But how can I import it only if it exists? This code is throwing me a 500 server error when I try to import a not existing yet file. This is my code (I'm using Vite to serve my app)

```
import(`./../Cache/${component.type.name}.svg?raw`)
.then(svgCode => console.log(svgCode))
.catch(err => {
    //here the file is created if it doesn't exists but it still throwing an error in the console
  })
```

It's not only about the error in the console, Vite is also throwing me this message:

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Atlantide/SvgRender/Cache/PixelGrid.svg'
Click outside or fix the code to dismiss.
You can also disable this overlay by setting server.hmr.overlay to false in vite.config.js.

But I don't wanna disable HMR in my setup, any advice?

Comment: You will have to instead make a http request to the asset, then you can handle it not being found accordingly.

Comment: Do you think there are any disadvantages or limitations in using that instead of the import?

Comment: Import happens at build time, so the file must always be there and is bundled within your project. Usually import is preferred for this reason, but in your case since the file isn't always present, so (I believe) fetching at runtime is the only option.

Comment: Or I was actually thinking i can import a standard static svg file like "import Cache from './cache.svg'), then looking there for my component and if it's not there add it. The file could get huge though but if that happens at build time I think it's gonna still be fast. Any thoughts around this? Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it